# How to access environment variables from apache2 configuration file?

Tags: javascript, html, apache

I am trying to make a part of my website where it will ask the user for a password in a prompt box, then allow access to the hidden content when the password is correct. I want to hide my password somewhere in my apache2 server; somewhere so that I can't just go to the javascript file containing the password in the URL bar, such as *[mywebsite]/password.js*. I tried doing

```
SetEnv PASSWORD password123
```

in my website configuration file for example, then in my javascript file linked to my HTML file I wrote the following code:

```
function check() {
    var password = process.env.PASSWORD;
    var str = prompt("Enter the correct password to continue: ");
    if (str != password) {
        check();
    }
    document.getElementById("visible").style.visibility = "visible";
}
```

However, when I load the website it loads but with the content still hidden. How can I hide the password in my server so that I could access it in my javascript file directly? Is there maybe a better way to do this? I should note that everything worked properly before trying to hide the password.

Comment: You should verify the password on the server using ajax :)

Comment: You're asking how to use X to achieve Y, but X isn't a suitable tool for that. What you need is a proper backend. I recommend starting with PHP ([xampp](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html)) (to clear up the confusion [or add to it], [`process`](https://nodejs.org/api/process.html) only exists in server-side JavaScript, not in a browser environment)

Comment: As @RohitSharma said, you have to verify the password on the server using AJAX. See, the JS is running on the browser which is a different environment from the server!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, process.env is not accessible from within a browser context. process.env is a nodejs variable. It will only exist in a nodejs-like environment. javascript in the browser does not run nodejs.

The simplest solution is to prevent access to the page using apache directly:

You would need to generate an .htpasswd file.

In your apache configuration, you would add something like this:

```
<Directory "/path/to/password/protected/folder">
    AuthType Basic
    AuthName "Restricted Content"
    AuthUserFile /path/to/htpasswd
    Require valid-user
</Directory>
```

Here's a complete guide for how to setup a password protected folder in apache:

https://web.archive.org/web/20200717044602/https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-password-authentication-with-apache-on-ubuntu-14-04

Comment: This is just what I needed. Thank you!